# unable to do a .find() loop in vue js component on created

Tags: javascript, loops, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I'm currently building a simple app with Vue js (and learnign it by the same occasion).

Here is the app : https://osr-app-2a8b6.web.app/

So when you are on the homepage that displays the list of events and then click on details, you end up on the single page of the event, that works perfectly, but when you load that single page without navigating to it (just reload the page), nothing is showing and I've got an

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'content' of undefined
```

which I don't have when navigating.

So here is the my router code :

```
const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes: [
        {name: 'home', path: '/', component: Home},
        {name: 'fav', path: '/favoris', component: FavoriteEvents},
        {name: 'single-event', path: '/:eventId', component: SingleEvent}
    ]
});
```

and my component :

```
<script>
    import SingleCta from './SingleCta.vue';
    import SingleHeader from './SingleHeader.vue';
    import PartnerList from './PartnerList.vue';
    import GalleryCarousel from './GalleryCarousel.vue';
    import TheProgram from './TheProgram.vue';
    import DropdownList from './DropdownList.vue';
    
    export default {
        components: {
            SingleCta,
            SingleHeader,
            PartnerList,
            GalleryCarousel,
            TheProgram,
            DropdownList,
        },
        data() {
            return {
                singleEvent: '',
                title: '',
                serieType: '',
                day: '',
                time: '',
                date: '',
                where: '',
                dropDowns: [],
                gallery: [],
                partners: [],
                people: [],
                program: '',
                description: '',
                adProgram: {},
                txtColor: '',
                bgColor: ''
            }
        },
        computed: {
            singleEventClass(){
                return 'page single-event ' + 'single-event--txt-' + this.txtColor + ' ' + 'single-event--bg-' + this.bgColor
            }
        },
        created() {
            const eventId = this.$route.params.eventId;
            const selectedEvent = this.$store.state.events.find(event => event.id === eventId);

            console.log(eventId) // return rhapsody-in-blue
            console.log(this.$store.state.events) // return my array with 3 events
            console.log(selectedEvent) // return undefined WHY???

            const selectedEventContent = selectedEvent.content;
            
            console.log(selectedEventContent) // return undefined WHY???

            this.singleEvent = selectedEvent;
            this.title = selectedEvent.title;
            this.serieType = selectedEvent.serieType;
            this.day = selectedEvent.day;
            this.date = selectedEvent.date;
            this.time = selectedEvent.time,
            this.where = selectedEvent.where,
            this.bgColor = selectedEvent.bgColor,
            this.txtColor = selectedEvent.txtColor,
            this.dropDowns = selectedEventContent.dropDowns;
            this.gallery = selectedEventContent.gallery
            this.partners = selectedEventContent.partners
            this.people = selectedEventContent.people
            this.program = selectedEventContent.program
            this.description = selectedEventContent.description
            this.adProgram = selectedEventContent.adProgram
        }
    }
</script>
```

the problem seems to be here:

```
const selectedEventContent = selectedEvent.content;
```

it returns me undefined :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'content' of undefined
```

but you can see that just before I'm logging the eventId and that returns the correct event ID:

```
rhapsody-in-blue
```

and also I'm logging the this.$store.state.events

which returns my events array :

```
Proxy {}
[[Handler]]: Object
[[Target]]: Array(3)
0: {bgColor: "pink", content: {…}, date: "30.09.20", day: "mercredi", id: "rhapsody-in-blue", …}
1: {bgColor: "pink", content: {…}, date: "23.09.21", day: "jeudi", id: "hommage-a-armin-jordan", …}
2: {bgColor: "black", content: {…}, date: "18.09.21", day: "samedi", id: "septembre-musical-montreux", …}
length: 3
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
[[IsRevoked]]: false
```

So why is the .find() loop on that array return me undefined?

Again that works when navigating but not on load.

Comment: Did you try to move the code form `created ` to `mounted`?

Comment: I have tried all the Lifecycle hooks (https://v3.vuejs.org/api/options-lifecycle-hooks.html), one by one, without success

Comment: Vue 3 react system was build on ProxyAPI, but can you try this:
`async created() {
            const eventId = this.$route.params.eventId;
            const selectedEvent = await this.$store.state.events.find(event => event.id === eventId);
....`

Comment: Yep but nope, it is still unable to get the content from the selected item

Comment: From my experience just refreshing your browser reinitializes a Vue app, which may be causing your problem  If you really need to refresh the detail page, create a 'Refresh' button that calls the app route for the detail page.

Comment: Are you sure you have `$store.state.events` available immediately, or do you need to wait for an API call to return them? You could use the `beforeRouteEnter` hook from vue-router to call/wait for certain actions or checks before you resume routing (by calling `next()`) to make sure it's available when you first load your component. I'd personally keep track of the selectedEvent by updating eventId in the store and writing a getter for the selectedEvent.

Comment: @Tim I don't particularly need to reload the page, but I need to access that page/screen when entering the url, without going through the home home screen. Excalibaard, I'm pretty sure you re right, I'm actually calling an API, and for sure the data is not ready when I display that screen. I'm going to do a couple of others tests with the different route hooks and I'll update my first post if necessary, thanks for the answers ;)